# SSRS 2008 R2 to SP integrated deployment scripting

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, reporting-services, sharepoint-2010

I've gone down a rabbit hole and finding it hard to know where to go now.

I have a report project I'm trying to script up for deployment to a SharePoint site on a highly controlled production server.  On my Dev box I can just deploy my project from BIDS and the reports run.  If I upload my rdls, datasets and datasource to the document library directly they don't.  I've done some digging and found that the uploaded files aren't linked in any way and that BIDS does some extra steps to set the DataSource for the Shared Datasets and then sets the reference to these DataSets on the Rdls.

So I've been poking around and can see that I need to call the SetItemReferences on ReportingServices2010.asmx to define the links but I'm lost using Powershell.  Some scripts I've found are focussed on setting DataSources so I'm trying to adapt that using bits from other scripts but getting lost.  One example does `$Reference = New-Object -TypeName SSRS.ReportingService2010.ItemReference` but I don't know where they're getting the `SSRS.` namespace from.

Incidentally, the structure I have is:
- One Shared DataSource points to a SharePoint List
- One DataSet pointing to the shared DataSource
- Four reports with NO embedded DataSources and five embedded DataSet references each pointing to the shared DataSet applying various filters.

Is there already a built in way to do this so I can avoid hassles?

Requirements here are that I need something extremely simple that doesn't require extra PowerShell modules to be installed (if possible).  The network is highly controlled and it's difficult enough to get scripts we run ourselves approed let alone some third party module installed on the farm of machines in Prod.  Basically it will take at least six months to scan, test and formally approve any addons but if we write a very simple script it's much easier.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - deploy with your browser.  I have written 3 separate report projects with SSRS on a highly controlled SharePoint 2010 production environment.  Each one of them, I have deployed using the browser.

Deploying using your browser is simpler than the PowerShell.  Follow the general steps [outlined in the last part of this thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/4d23f9fe-9df5-462f-a5d5-d03cca817a28/how-do-i-deploy-a-ssrs-2008-r2-file-to-sharepoint-2010?forum=sharepointadminprevious).  Doing it via Powershell is possible, but far more difficult task.

If the admins have this production environment so highly controlled, then there should exist a parallel staging environment that is kept in precise configuration as production and available to you in order to do [DevOps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DevOps) of your SSRS reports.  You should request to test your install on the staging environment in order to work out your deployment issues (either by browser or PowerShell).  If you get denied this request, then you need to request again.  Otherwise its impossible to get it perfect if you don't have access to develop on a similar system.

DevOps on these reports is the last mile of the race and can be difficult if you are the first to do it at your organization.  You can do it, just keep going and your reports will be installed.  Keep good notes so when you development future reports you can repeat this process and will be the go-to person for getting it done in the future.  Don't lose faith.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  My only issue is the potential for errors to introduced by doing things manually. Specifically in this case the user would have to set 25 dataset references via the web interface which is risky and convolutes testing

Comment: I understand your concern, @StephenYork.  But this is normal for SSRS reports.  SSRS are very powerful, but integration with SharePoint is brittle, you will often need to do manual fixes to these data source files, rdls, etc.  For example, If the customer ever wants to move the location of the reports, or change the lists, Migrate to 2013,  or make simple changes to the report, DevOps will need to be performed on these files.  You can't script this easily.  Its simplest just to do it with the browser and very tough(expensive) to automate.

Comment: So, since I put the question up I have come up with a Powershell script to go do all the linkages from the rdls to rds but I'm having issues with the rsds. I was under the impression renaming from rds to rsds was all the was needed but alas the whole xml document is different when you simply build the project compared with what gets uploaded when you "Deploy" from BIDS.  Whether I do it with my script or manuall I still get the same error about the schema being wrong. Is there a way to get BIDS to automatically output the rsds?